# extern derived object instance in library does not get created

Tags: c++

I have this sample code to demonstrate the issue I'm facing.

main.cpp

```
#include "opengl_renderer.h"

int main ( void )
{
    renderer_class *pointer = renderer_class::get_instance();
    printf ( "Pointer is %p\n", pointer );
    if ( pointer )
        pointer->print();
    return 0;
}
```

renderer.cpp

```
#include "renderer.h"
#include "opengl_renderer.h"
renderer_class *renderer_class::instance = NULL;

opengl_renderer opengl_renderer_instance;

renderer_class::renderer_class ( void )
{
    printf ( "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
    instance = this;
}

void renderer_class::print ( void )
{
    printf ( "print from renderer class\n" );
}

renderer_class *renderer_class::get_instance ( void )
{
    return instance;
}
```

renderer.h

```
#ifndef renderer_included
#define renderer_included
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class renderer_class
{
private:
    static renderer_class *instance;
public:
    renderer_class ( void );
    virtual void print ( void );
    static renderer_class *get_instance ( void );
};

#endif
```

opengl_renderer.cpp

```
#include "opengl_renderer.h"
//opengl_renderer opengl_renderer_instance;
opengl_renderer::opengl_renderer ( void )
{
    printf ( "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
}

void opengl_renderer::print ( void )
{
    printf ( "print from opengl class\n" );
}
```

opengl_renderer.h

```
#ifndef opengl_renderer_included
#define opengl_renderer_included

#include "renderer.h"

class opengl_renderer : public renderer_class
{
public:
    opengl_renderer ( void );
    void print ( void );
};

extern opengl_renderer opengl_renderer_instance;
#endif
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library ( renderer_lib renderer.cpp renderer.h opengl_renderer.cpp opengl_renderer.h )
add_executable ( main main.cpp )
target_link_libraries ( main renderer_lib )
```

Basically, a base class ( renderer ), and a derived class ( opengl_renderer ) from it. I declare an extern instance of the opengl_renderer class in the opengl_renderer header. All these files are compiled into the same library. For some reason, if I declare/instantiate the instance in the opengl_renderer class cpp file, it never gets instantiated, but if declare/instantiate it in the base renderer class cpp file, then it does.

If I build and run this code, this is the output:

```
renderer_class::renderer_class()
opengl_renderer::opengl_renderer()
Pointer is 0x10b306090
print from opengl class
```

But, if I comment this line

```
opengl_renderer opengl_renderer_instance;
```

in renderer.cpp, and uncomment that same line in opengl_renderer.cpp, the output is

```
Pointer is 0x0
```

Why does it behave like this? Is the linker removing my opengl class declaration when declared in the opengl, so it it not detecting that it is actually being used?
If so, why does it behave differently just because I declare it on the base cpp file? Its the same library, shouldn't it NOT be cutting away my instantiation?

Comment: Order of initialization of globals between translation units is undefined. Look [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) for example.

Comment: @Rostislav In this case initialization order is well-defined even between translation units because "Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place."(std 3.6.2)  and `instance = NULL;` requires static initialization while `opengl_renderer_instance` requires dynamic initialization.

Comment: also, if the problem were with the pointer, that could be correct. But, if you check, you'd see that the printf's inside the constructors were never run. That object was simply never built.

Comment: @Joao Pincho notice that `opengl_renderer_instance` is located in static library and not used explicitly in executable therefore it is not required to be created at all. It looks like it is getting constructed while defined in the same translation unit as `instance` because compiler detects the side effect of the constructor of `opengl_renderer_instance` that changes `instance`. If your remove `instance = this;` then `opengl_renderer_instance` will never be constructed even when defined in the same translation unit.

Comment: @VTT Yep, jumped into conclusions too quickly.

Comment: @Rostislav I get that, I understand that the linker is for some reason not detecting that I am actually using the object by declaring it, but what I don't get is why does it detect it if I declare it on the base cpp file but not on the derived one. The linker trimming of unused objects should be done only at the linker stage, when all the object files are compiled, when it gets linked with the main code. Is it possible that the linker is for some reason trimming the object on a per-object-file basis, instead of per-library-basis?